# HTML iframe with dash output

Tags: python, html, iframe, plotly-dash

I have 2 pretty simple dashboards and I would like to run this two dashboards with flask using main.py for routing.

app1.py

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('App 1'),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph1',
            figure={
                'data': [{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'App 1'}],
                'layout': {
                    'title': 'App 1 Graph'
                }
            }
        )
    ]
)
```

and

app2.py

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('App 2'),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph2',
            figure={
                'data': [{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 1], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'App 2'}],
                'layout': {
                    'title': 'App 2 Graph'
                }
            }
        )
    ]
)
```

main.py

```
# main_app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import app1
import app2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Main App'

@app.route('/app1')
def render_dashboard1():
    return render_template('dashboard1.html')

@app.route('/app2')
def render_dashboard2():
    return render_template('dashboard2.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

dashboard1.html

```
<!-- dashboard1.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard 1</h1>
    <iframe src="/app1" width="1000" height="800"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard2.html

```
<!-- dashboard2.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard 2</h1>
    <iframe src="/app2" width="1000" height="800"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

> structure
>
> ```
> /
> app1.py
> app2.py
> main.py
> /templates
> dashboard1.html
> dashboard2.html
> ```

but when I run my main.py and route for app1 I can see frame for the app1 but there is no graph.
Could someone please explain how to use iframe to for me to be able to see output?

Comment: When I access `/app1` (and 2) I get **Not Found** error. Maybe your browser is caching and you should Ctrl+F5 or use a new port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't access the templates with your code, I think `dask` uses `flask` so this may be causing problems.
What I have done is calling two dash apps and one flask app; this for **main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from app1 import create_app as create_app1
from app2 import create_app as create_app2

server = Flask(__name__)
app1 = create_app1(server)
app2 = create_app2(server)


@server.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Main App'


def render_dashboard1():
    return render_template('dashboard1.html')


def render_dashboard2():
    return render_template('dashboard2.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

Use the method `create_app` for each `app`, **app1.py**:

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc


def create_app(server):
    app = dash.Dash(server=server, routes_pathname_prefix='/app1/')

    app.layout = html.Div(
        children=[
            html.H1('App 1'),
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph1',
                figure={
                    'data': [{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'App 1'}],
                    'layout': {
                        'title': 'App 1 Graph'
                    }
                }
            )
        ]
    )

    return app
```

and **app2.py** (I changed `y` values to be sure it is reading the **app2** template):

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc


def create_app(server):
    app = dash.Dash(server=server, routes_pathname_prefix='/app2/')

    app.layout = html.Div(
        children=[
            html.H1('App 2'),
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph2',
                figure={
                    'data': [{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [10, 10, 10], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'App 2'}],
                    'layout': {
                        'title': 'App 2 Graph'
                    }
                }
            )
        ]
    )

    return app
```

and I can see both graphs correctly.